# Interpreting group's representations

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups

I'm attending an undergraduate course in Group Theory and as far as I understood each representation of a Lie group can be identified with a specific basis of *V* vector space on which the representation acts. I was wondering whether or not from this assumption (since during the course the teacher didn't mentioned it explicitly) it is possible to interpret the different representations of a group over *V* starting from the fundamental and changing basis.

Thanks in advance to everyone!

Comment: There is no specific basis attached to a representation.  Of course, writing down a representation explicitly might entail choosing a basis.

Comment: What do you mean by "identified with a specific basis"? As far as I remember, not every representation has invariant basis, not even for finite groups. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: I meant that specifying a base is sufficient to identify a representation, although it seems I'm wrong. I thought that because in the material given for the course, when explaining the algebra of SU(3), it was said that the vectors (1,0,0) (0,1,0) and (0,0,1) form THE basis of the representation 3.

Comment: I suggest, you work out some simple examples and read some reputable textbook. What you wrote is mostly a result of a misconception.

Comment: You can have a representation without a basis and you can have a basis without a representation. So I don't understand what the question is.